# Not able to show border color and background as blur in custom view as popup view in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, popup, xib

I have some requirement to show popup as some customisation options.

So, I took custom view as UIView with Xib file.

```
class CustomAlertView : UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var customAlertView : UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var button1 : UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2 : UIButton!

override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomAlertView", owner: self)
    guard let content = customAlertView else { return }
    content.frame = self.bounds
    content.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    self.addSubview(content)
}
```

}

And given outlet connections.

And I am able to load the view in viewcontroller class.

But, the issue is, its not showing as pop up view and its not showing any border color, etc even I added too.

And the present self.view (Main view from viewcontroller) still moving it has tableview, while I clicking on the buttons on custom view, nothing happening.

```
   func someAction() {
        self.view.addSubview(customAlert)
        self.customAlert.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        self.customAlert.layer.borderWidth = 10
        self.customAlert.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.customAlert.clipsToBounds = false
        let radius: CGFloat = self.customAlert.frame.width / 2.0 //change it to .height if you need spread for height

        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2.1 * radius, height: self.customAlert.frame.height))

        self.customAlert.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.customAlert.layer.cornerRadius = 8; // if you like rounded corners
        self.customAlert.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:-15, height:20);
        self.customAlert.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.customAlert.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        self.customAlert.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath

        self.customAlert.byMonthlyBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.customAlert.byAnnuallyBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button2tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

And its looks like below screenshot

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of how it looks like now?

Comment: Updated query please check

Answer (score 0):

```
private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomAlertView", owner: self)
    guard let content = customAlertView else { return }
    content.frame = self.bounds
    content.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    self.addSubview(content)
}
```

Your problem is you are using the **CustomAlertView** you loaded. Try adjust your code like below.

```
private func commonInit() {
    guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomAlertView", owner: self)?.first as? CustomAlertView else {   
        return
    }
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    addSubview(view)
}
```